# JavaScript inheritance with _.extend()

Tags: javascript, oop

Whats the difference between

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

and

```
_.extend(Employee.prototype, Person.prototype);
```

Both give similar results (output), but the underscore method seems to add the Person.prototype to the Employee.constructor.prototype, and quite abit extra stuff here and there, why?

pure JS

[image]

underscoreJS

[image]

A nice side effect of `_.extend` is I can easily do multiple inheritance: seems like it doesnt make the prototype chain longer too ...

```
_.extend(Employee.prototype, Person.prototype);
_.extend(Employee.prototype, {
    doSomething: function() {
        return "hi ...";
    }
});
```

But ...

[image]

Why is there 2 sayHi and doSomething functions? (actually its the same when I just do 1 extend).

**http://jsfiddle.net/VMqSy/1/**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With `Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);` you are completely replacing the `Employee.prototype`.

But with `_.extend(Employee.prototype, Person.prototype);` you are adding the `Person.prototype` on top of the `Employee.prototype`.

For example,

```
var a = {var1:1, var2:2};
var b = {var2:4, var3:3};
console.log(_.extend(a, b)); // {var1:1, var2:4, var3:3}
```

As you see, `a` it's not completely replaced by `b`, it's just *extended* by the properties defined in `b`.

Comment: Another difference is `_.extend` seems to extend `constructor.prototype` (not `.extend`)? Are they the "same"? Apart from them in different places?

Comment: `_.extend` modifies the first object passed, so, in my example, `b` remains untouched, but `a` it's actually extended by `b`.

In `_.extend({}, a, b)`, `a` and `b` remains untouched, and `{}` it's extended by their properties.

Comment: Note that if you do it that way, i.e. `_.extend(Employee.prototype, Person.prototype);`, any instance created with `new` will give you back an `Employee`, and that Employee shall not be a `Person`, i.e. `new Employee() instanceof Person` should be `false`.